# Wife name not found after logging in CEAC

Tags: usa, immigration

My sister applied for the US immigration F4 category for our three persons. Me, my wife and my child. Recently we got a welcome letter after logging in Department of State's Consular Electronic Application Center (CEAC) I found my name and my child name but my wife's name is not found.

**I wanted to know that does it was a mistake**. If this is a mistake then what can I do?